# Multiple PHP requests waiting for one

Tags: php, ajax, concurrency

I'm currently developing a website. I want to cache results from an API but the API is slow, so I must handle concurrent PHP requests for same result.

When a PHP is collecting API results for a certain ID, I want next PHP requests for same ID to wait the first to finish and just read the cached value.

My current solution is to add an empty value in cache (and if value is empty new PHP requests will just sleep and recheck) but it sometimes doesn't work.

Is there another or a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using synchronization provided by PECL Sync library and SyncReaderWriter class, or just by simple File Locking System.

If You want working solution, I've created PHP Cache library that synchronize read/write process especially for task like You described above.

I think you may find it useful, check it here: https://github.com/tztztztz/php-no-slam-cache